# How to use upright pound signs with lmodern and textcomp

Tags: xetex, symbols, luatex, textcomp, lmodern

I would like to use an *upright* pound sign, however, due to the packages I am using, it has been replaced with a curly variant which is less in-keeping with the surrounding text.

Ideal:

[image: Upright pound sign]

Current output:

[image: Curly pound sign]

I have found that that

- When compiling with `xelatex` or `lualatex`, the **curly** variant is always produced.
- When compiling with `pdflatex` **with** the `lmodern` and `textcomp` packages, the **curly** variant is output
- When compiling with `pdflatex` **without** the `lmodern` and `textcomp` packages, the **upright** variant is output

My question - is there a way of using the upright pound sign without removing either package?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}
\begin{document}
    \pounds{}100
\end{document}
```

Comment: According to "A guide to LuaLaTeX", ctan package lualatex-doc, section 1.2, you should not use textcomp on lualatex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shape of the sterling sign is the one the designers of Latin Modern chose.

You can revert to the Computer Modern design (actually, European Modern):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}

\let\pounds\relax
\DeclareRobustCommand{\pounds}{%
  \ifmmode\mathsterling\else{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\textsterling}\fi
}

\begin{document}

\pounds 100

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Both versions are curly. Simply they're  different: one is the Computer Modern version, the other the Latin Modern.  Though they're very close, there are some differences, in particular Computer Modern looks blacker.
If you want the Computer Modern version with `xelatex`, you can load `CM Unicode`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

\Huge

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}\pounds \,10

\fontspec{lmroman12-regular.otf}
\pounds \,10

\end{document}
```

[image]